# Send images from server to android app

Tags: android, ksoap2, httpurlconnection

I have an Android app that fetches data from the web service using ksoap2, the web service in turn fetches that information from SQL Server and sends it to the app, ksoap2 is fast and reliable and I'm happy with it.

I'm about to add a new feature which is the app will fetch multiple images from the server too. I searched for the best way to do this and I landed on three options:

- keep using ksoap2 and store the images on the SQL Server, the web service will send the images in binary strings and then the app with render them and display them.
- Store the images on the hard drive and use HttpUrlConnection, the web service will send the images path (url) through ksoap2 and the app will use HttpUrlConnection to download the images and display them.
- Use JSon

My question is, from your experience which way should I go for? or maybe you have a better solution than that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use option #2:

> Store the images on the hard drive and use HttpUrlConnection, the web service will send the images path (url) through ksoap2 and the app will use HttpUrlConnection to download the images and display them.

This gives you the benefits of ksoap2, without a hacky workaround trying to jam images into SQL binary strings.

Additionally (and this is without knowing anything about the app you are creating) it allows you to only load the images when you actually need them, saving bandwidth, battery and memory.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm going to go that way because I dont know how stable will ksoap2 be with handling large binary strings. also form what I read in some websites, storing images on the hard drive is a better option than storing them in the database.